# importing a raw file (keystore) in my app

Tags: android, ssl, https, import, keystore

I am trying to import a keystore file into my app. I have it in my `res/raw`folder. 
I looked at other questions on stackoverflow but was not able to find any working solution for this.

I have tried using

```
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
```

It leads to `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: The codes seems good. what's the file name?

Comment: Finally, i got it working. The problem was, that i was using this inside a constructor. And you don't have your context available until you have exited the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got it working.

The problem was, that i was using this inside a constructor. And you don't have your context available until you have exited the constructor. That's it.